# How to insert the ISBLANK into an already valid formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to add or modify the current formula in Google sheets:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('14_Day_Drop'!B2:B=FALSE, "YES", "NO"))

the formula above works exactly the way I want it, BUT.... I would like to add that if the cells are blank in the array to leave them blank this where this formula is located at. Right now it has YES all the way down the whole row.... I would like to eliminate that so it would be cleaner.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have already tried this:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('14_Day_Drop'!B2:B=FALSE, "YES", "NO"), ""))

I get an ERROR: Wrong # of arguments to ISBLANK. Expected 1 arguments but got 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('14_Day_Drop'!B2:B="",,
              IF('14_Day_Drop'!B2:B=FALSE, "YES", "NO")))
```

Comment: Thank you @rockinfreakshow, but that does not work. It is causing an error issue of Parse of words.

Comment: rockinfreakshow solved this for me. Thanks. It wouldn't let me edit my first comment.